# how to find the inflection point of an exponential curve?

Tags: exponential-function, curves, decreasing-rearrangements, inflection-point

I have a set of decreasing numbers for example  18.98, 15.45, 11.7, 9.73, 9.06, 1.47, 0.1323, 0.1081, 0.0896, 0.0797, 0.0732.

I want to find the inflection point in this set of numbers which is supposed to be 1.47? is it possible?

I will use the methematical solution to code it using matlab.

I cant use a specific threshold value since the numbers will be always random.

Comment: An inflection point is usually where the curvature changes from positive to negative.  An exponential has no inflection point.

Answer (score 1):

What you call the "inflection point" seems to be the median. If the list is sorted then the median is the halfway point, or the average of the two halfway points if the number of entries is even.

As @NicNic8 notes, matlab can do this for you: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html

Comment: It does.  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html